# How to catch all error-codes at once

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, error-handling, web.xml

How can i catch all error-codes at once? 
i tried `*` but it didnt work.

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>javax.servlet.error.status_code</error-code>  
  <location>/default_error_page.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that according to the web.xml [XSD](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd). You'll have to specify each error code separately.

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph mentioned, there is no way of doing that from the XSD, **but*** the way to do what you want is by using a filter. If the filter catches any exception, then you can return any content you want.

Of course this solution works as long as the server hasn't sent the headers back to the client.